# Signal Processing Data to Live Plotting(FFT and GNUPLOT in c++)

Tags: c++, plot, gnuplot, signal-processing, fft

I am working on a project where I get data from 0 to 255, If this data matches certain criteria,whether it follows a certain string, it is directly plotting using `Gnuplot`, else it just gets stored in a data.txt file.

The issues I am facing:

1. The graph I'm plotting is not smooth but is jagged. I would like to
   smoothen the data by processing it using `FFTW3` or some program
   like that. I need to do this so I can analyze the data for further
   reference.
2. I read about the Fast Fourier transform and I'm not sure how I will apply the Fourier to my strings of numbers which I receive.

Please do help me with the code that I should employ.

*Conclusion:*

I get data in the form of continuous strings of numbers which I need to effectively smoothen out and plot it in a live graph.

Comment: Your question is ill-formatted, unclear and in general displays your lack of understanding for the issues you're dealing with.  Just as an example of the weakness of your question: where is your data coming from? is it continuously arriving or does it come in discrete, identifiable pieces? Even if someone were willing to help you, they won't be able because of the complete lack of details. I suggest that you delete this question, begin to work on your problem and come back to  ask answerable questions...

Answer (score 1):

Fast Fourier is an overkill for your application, you just need to lowpass filter your samples to reduce the noise.

I'm assuming your sample input has a constant rate, so:

1) Identify the maximum frequency you're interested in. (An spectrogram or a Fourier plot of you samples might help here to identify it, use a math software for it (octave, matlab, numpy, etc)).

2) Design a digital low pass filter with break frequency above your target maximum (processing all samples, not just the ones you want to print).

3) Print the ones you want.

Comment: FFT filters are very fast ( O(n log n)). Your lowpass in the time domain would have to average very few points to be faster than an FFT method.

Comment: @roadrunner66 I said overkill, not faster. It's easier to implement a time domain FIR, and probably fast enough. `the time domain would have to average very few points` and that will depend on the sample rate, the target response and the decimation ratio, all things we don't know.